# Magento 2 jsonParse() does not receive data, Unexpected token '

Tags: magento2, javascript, template, json

I'm creating a js template in Magento 2. When I call js, I get an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'in JSON at position 96`. Why `jsonParse ()` does not get the value? Can somebody help me?

file .phtml

```
<?php
$productData = [
    ["sku"=>"Tshirt-Red",
        "name"=>"Tshirt Red Armani",
        "price"=>"5000"],
    ["sku"=>"Tshirt-Blue",
            "name"=>"Tshirt Blue Armani",
            "price"=>"6000"],
    ["sku"=>"Tshirt-Yellow",
            "name"=>"Tshirt Yellow Armani",
            "price"=>"7000"]
        ];
$jsonProductData = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data')->jsonEncode($productData);
?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
                "Bss_JsTemplate/js/jstemplate":{
                "Data" : '<?php echo $jsonProductData; ?>'
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<script id="product-template" type="text/x-magento-template">
    <% _.each(data, function(value, key) { %>
    <ul>
        <li> Product <%-key %>  : <%- value %></li>
    </ul>
    <% }); %>
</script>
<button id="getInfo">Get  Info</button>
<div id ="product" style="display: none;"></div>
```

file jstemplate.js

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "mage/template"
], function ($, template) {
    "use strict";
     return function (config, element) {
        var product;
        $.each($.parseJSON(config.Data), function () {
            var productTemplate = template('#product-template');
            product = productTemplate({
                data: {
                    sku: this['sku'],
                    name: this['name'],
                    price: this['price']
                }
            });
            $('#product').append(product);
        });
        $("#getInfo").click(function () {
            $("#product").toggle();
        });
    };
});
```

error :
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

JSON standard doesn't allow the single quote('). We need to use the double quote ("). 
But, in your case, I think we don't need to use the double quote. Just simply uses: (Not test yet)

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
                "Bss_JsTemplate/js/jstemplate":{
                "Data" : <?php echo $jsonProductData; ?>
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

And `$productData` array should look like:

```
$productData = [
  'data' => [
     ["sku"=>"Tshirt-Red",
        "name"=>"Tshirt Red Armani",
        "price"=>"5000"],
    ["sku"=>"Tshirt-Blue",
            "name"=>"Tshirt Blue Armani",
            "price"=>"6000"],
    ["sku"=>"Tshirt-Yellow",
            "name"=>"Tshirt Yellow Armani",
            "price"=>"7000"] 
   ]
]
```

In your each statement, don't need to use `$.pareJSON()` function.

Comment: Tks u. How can I get "Data" into jsonParse (). I tried that but jsonParse () could not get the value.Can u help me ?

Comment: statement in the file js   $.each($.parseJSON(config.Data), function () {

Comment: `config.Data` doesn't give any value?

Comment: hmm.When I put "Data": <? php echo $ jsonProductData; ?>  and $ .each ($. parseJSON (config.Data), function () {. I still have the same error

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong. How about using the double quote (")?  `"Data": "<? php echo $ jsonProductData; ?>"`

Comment: put "Data": "<? php echo $ jsonProductData;" ?> .I do not fault that there is an error due to jsonParse (config.Data) missing single quote (').

Comment: How do you set a variable with a single quote?

Comment: `"Data": "<? php echo $ jsonProductData; ?>"`? Could you try again?

Comment: yes.i have tried.but i get an error Unexpected token "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84144/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-thanh-trung-to).